# how to access arraylist data in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

i have:

```
var itemOrder = ArrayList<String>()
```

file model Order.kt:

```
private var itemName:String? = null
private var note:String? = null
private var price: CharSequence? = null
private var all: Int? = null
private var quantity: Int? = null

fun Order(itemName: String, price: CharSequence, all: Int, note: String, quantity: Int)
    {
        this.itemName = itemName
        this.price = price
        this.all = all
        this.note = note
        this.quantity = quantity
    }
```

then i add for itemOrder like this:

```
itemOrder.add(Order.Order(finalHolder1.nameItem!!.text.toString(),`finalHolder1 priceItem!!.text, finalHolder1.quantity, finalHolder1.note!!.text.toString(), finalHolder1.quantity * hargaSatuan).toString())
```

then

```
fun cart(): ArrayList<String> {
    return itemOrder
}
```

i want to see all item value where i have add before to itemOrder in Toast like

> itemName : valueofValue
>
> price: valueofprice
>
> all: valueofall
>
> note: valueofnote
>
> quantity: valueofquantity

```
Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "List Item : "+ cart(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

but i get this result:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXQex.jpg)

i want change result of kotlin.init to value each array in array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of primitive String type , arraylist should be "Order" of type;

```
 var itemOrder = ArrayList<Order>()
```

Instead of how you defined the model class, define as

```
data class Order(

      val itemName:String,
      val note:String,
      val price: CharSequence,
      val all: Int,
      val quantity: Int
);
```

// add item as

```
itemOrder.add(Order(finalHolder1.nameItem!!.text.toString(),`finalHolder1 priceItem!!.text, finalHolder1.quantity, finalHolder1.note!!.text.toString(), finalHolder1.quantity * hargaSatuan).toString())
```

// print each value as

```
fun( 0 in until itemOrder.size){

   Log.e("name",itemOrder[i].itemName);
   //get all data in the same way
}
```

Comment: i got this error for
Error:(144, 31) Type mismatch: inferred type is String but Order was expected

in line:
itemOrder.add(Order(finalHolder1.nameItem!!.text.toString(),`finalHolder1 priceItem!!.text, finalHolder1.quantity, finalHolder1.note!!.text.toString(), finalHolder1.quantity * hargaSatuan).toString())

Comment: you havn't change the arraylist type @mip

Comment: like this right ? var itemOrder = ArrayList<Order>()

i get suggestion from IDE: Create extension function 'ArrayList<Order>.add'

private fun <E> ArrayList<E>.add(element: String) {}

no got error, but item now insert to itemOrder

Comment: ah, my bad type String from required i put different. sorry now its work thanks :D

Comment: If my answer solved you problem then upvote my question